# One to few relation in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to mongodb and I want to have a one to few relationship in my database. I want to have an embedded schema but I am struggling to make it work. I want a user to have many posts but when I am trying to insert data then only name,email and password are getting inserted and not blogs. I am stuck and any help would be appreciated.

```js
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import Cors from "cors";
const app=express();
const port= process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(Cors());

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://@cluster0.gmg3q.mongodb.net/NotScr?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

const userSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    blog: [{
        title: String,
        post: String
    }]
});

const User= mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    res.send("Hello World!Welcome to NOTSCRAP backend");
});

app.post("/register", (req,res)=>{
    const newUser = req.body;
    User.create(newUser, (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            res.send(err)
        } else{
            res.send(data);
        }
    });
});

app.post("/login", (req, res)=>{
    const user_email = req.body.email;
    const user_password = req.body.password;
    User.findOne({email: user_email}, function(err, foundUser){
        if(err){
            console.log("Wrong Email");
            res.send("Wrong Email");
        } else{
            if(foundUser){
                if(foundUser.password === user_password){
                    console.log(foundUser);
                    res.send(foundUser);
                } else{
                    console.log("Wrong Password");
                    res.send("Wrong Password");
                }
            } else{
                res.send("Wrong Email");
                console.log("Wrong Email");
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(req.body);
});

app.post("/userdata", (req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.body);
    const id=req.body.username;
    User.findOne({_id: id}, function(err, foundUser){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else{
            console.log(foundUser);
            res.send(foundUser);
        }
    });
});

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server is up and running on port ${port}`);
})
```

Comment: From the code you shared, I see only the `/register` endpoint inserting into the database so I want to assume that's where the issue is. Can you share what the payload of your `/register` endpoint looks like? i.e the content of `req.body`

Comment: I got the solution for that. The data was not passed correctly that is why it was showing error.

Comment: Good to hear you fixed it... I would suggest you mark this question as answered so others won't' spend time/effort trying to answer what has already been solved.